# Is it possible to add a custom JAXWS generator into CXF codegen tool?

Tags: java, cxf, cxf-codegen

The CXF codegen tool is able to generate different classes like SEI/Port, Impl, Service, Faults, etc. (from WSDL/XSD) all through specific implementations of `AbstractJAXWSGenerator` and ViewMaker templates.

Is it possible to give the codegen tool a custom generator/vm template (via xml config, META-INF/services, whatever)?

I would like to do that to generate a decorator class of my SEI/Port: this class would implement the SEI and take an other SEI instance to which it would delegate all calls while doing some generic stuff with the request/response/fault objects inside the methods.

I know I could achieve the same result with a java `Proxy` of my SEI but given that a lot of code is already generated for JAX-WS and JAXB, I would like to try to add some of my own.